# Api do not return response with promise handling, works without it

Tags: go-ethereum, windows

I have already deployed ethereum private blockchain network on linux and on windows 10, but api's do not return response. 
For example

```
contract.methods.freezeAccount(address,tempStatus).send({from:'042b1b16eccb6c6bafdceaafea5e9e117990feef'}).then((result)=>{
                        res.send('Account Frozen:'+' '+address+' '+tempStatus);
                }).catch((error)=>{
                        res.send("Invalid Address");
                })
```

It does get executed but it is not returning response.

Using this to interact with api from console.

```
curl -v http://10.200.10.64:3000/freezeAccount/0x191e6cf5f81c9a6864c4e157fadde3c94967e321/false
*   Trying 10.200.10.64...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.200.10.64 (10.200.10.64) port 3000 (#0)
 GET /freezeAccount/0x191e6cf5f81c9a6864c4e157fadde3c94967e321/false HTTP/1.1
 Host: 10.200.10.64:3000
 User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
 Accept: */*
```

Following works

```
contract.methods.freezeAccount(address,tempStatus).send({from: '0x042b1b16eccb6c6bafdceaafea5e9e117990feef'}, (error, transactionHash) => {
                        if(!error)
                        res.send('Account Frozen:'+' '+address+' '+tempStatus);
                        else
                        res.send("Invalid Address");
                });
```

But it throws following nodejs warning on console

```
(node:11200) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11200) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: There are many possible reasons, try to narrow where it is hanging. Is it in the call to the geth client? Is it in the api server? Compare the versions of the package installed against the working version. Also I've noticed the `from` is missing `0x` in front.

Comment: I have tried with adding 0x but same issue. Other api's like creating wallet or checking balance are working fine. But this one is giving me trouble. On geth it get stuck on commit new mining work and doesn't show successfully sealed new block unless curl returns empty reply or or forcefully stop curl command and then it shows successfully sealed new block

Comment: I have updated details kindly look into it. It is giving error when converting for promise handling

Comment: Check the transaction receipt, perhaps the function `freezeAccount` is failing and causes the promise to reject.

Comment: Working fine now. Without using ".then", it works fine. Thanks